# Open Source SIP client for Iphone

Tags: iphone

I want to write a SIP clent in Xcode and want to make call using SIP. Where will I find open source SIP client for Iphone (objective c)?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

siphon is there since ages. you can check it out.

http://code.google.com/p/siphon/

Answer (score 1):

Check linphone i was using that, http://www.linphone.org/

Comment: is it still open-source? I could not find any link to their source for ios.